# Linear Regression of Quadratic Points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistical-inference, regression

I was casually experimenting with Desmos's linear regression and noticed some patterns in the best fit line for points which fit `y = x^2`.

For `(0,0) and (1,1)` the best fit line is `y = 1x+0` and `r = 1` (the correlation coefficient).

For `(0,0) , (1,1) , (2,4) , ... , (10,100)` the best fit line is `y = 10x-15` and `r = .963`.

And for `(0,0) , (1,1) , (2,4) , ... , (20,400)` the best fit line is `y = 20x-63.333` and `r = .965`.

My questions are:

- Why is the best fit slope always equal to the # of points - 1?
- Does the y-intercept follow the curve -$1/6 x^2 + 1/2 x - 1/3$ where x is the # of points?
- Does the correlation coefficient approach $1$, and why does it even increase as more points are added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What is the formula for the line of best fit here?

In this case, because the points we take follow an algebraic pattern, we can calculate a linear regression on the points $\{(0,0), (1,1), (2,4), \dots, (n,n^2)\}$ in terms of $n$, and see what happens.

To do this, we start with the overconstrained system of equations that a line $y=ax+b$ passes through all $n+1$ points: $0 = a\cdot0+b$, $1=a\cdot1+b$, and so on through $n^2 = a\cdot n+b$. In matrix form, $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0^2 \\ 1^2 \\ 2^2 \\ \vdots \\ n^2\end{bmatrix}.$$ There is no such line; to find the least-squares solution, we multiply by the transpose of the coefficient matrix: $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \\ \vdots & \vdots \\ 1 & n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 2 & \cdots & n\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0^2 \\ 1^2 \\ 2^2 \\ \vdots \\ n^2\end{bmatrix}.$$ This simplifies to a $2\times 2$ system $$\begin{bmatrix}n+1 & \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \\ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} & \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} \\ \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}\end{bmatrix}$$ where the increasingly complicated formulas in the cells are the sum of our $x$-coordinates, the sum of their squares, and the sum of their cubes. Solving this system gets us a general formula for $a$ and $b$: the line of best fit is $$y = nx -\frac{n(n-1)}{6}.$$

(This *does* fit the conjecture formula in the question.)

### Why?

It's hard to answer "why" questions when the real "why" is "because the formula said so".

It is reasonable to expect a slope approximately equal to $n$, because this is the slope from the first to the last point: $\frac{n^2-0}{n-0}$. This doesn't tell us that the slope must be exactly $n$, but sometimes math does nice things for us.

We can also get some insight into the problem by rescaling. Divide all $x$-coordinates by $n$ and all $y$-coordinates by $n^2$. Our $n+1$ points are now $(0,0), (\frac1n, \frac1{n^2}), (\frac2n, \frac4{n^2}), \dots, (1,1)$: they are $n+1$ evenly-spaced points on the graph of $y=x^2$ for $x$ between $0$ and $1$. As $n$ increases, our line of best fit should get closer and closer to some line best approximating that graph...

...and it does; rescaling our line of best fit gives us $y = x - \frac16 + \frac1{6n}$, and this approaches $y = x - \frac16$ as $n$ increases.

### What about the correlation coefficient?

The [most convenient formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#For_a_sample) to use here is
$$r_{xy} = \frac{n\sum x_i y_i - \sum x_i\sum y_i}
{\sqrt{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}~\sqrt{n\sum y_i^2-\left(\sum y_i\right)^2}}$$
Here, each sum is one of the familiar expressions $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, $ \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, or $\frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$, except that $\sum y_i^2 = \sum_{i=0}^n i^4$, which has a more complicated formula I'm scared to write down.

To avoid getting into those weeds, we approximate $\sum x_i \approx n^2/2$, $\sum x_i^2 = \sum y_i \approx n^3/3$, $\sum x_iy_i \approx n^4/4$, and $\sum y_i^2 \approx n^5/5$.  (The general rule for the approximation is that when we have a sum of $r^{\text{th}}$ powers, $\sum_{i=0}^n i^r$, it is approximately $n^{r+1}/(r+1)$. One way to get there is to replace the sum by an integral.)

This approximation simplifies the numerator to about $n^5/12$, the first square root to $\sqrt{n^4/12}$, and the second square root to $\sqrt{4n^6/45}$. Overall, the factors of $n$ cancel, and we get $$r_{xy} \approx \frac{\sqrt{15}}{4} \approx  0.968246.$$
Because we took our approximations, this only gets us the limiting behavior: if you like, the correlation coefficient for $y = x^2$ when $0 \le x \le 1$, with line of best fit $y = x - \frac16$. The correlation coefficient for small $n$ will only approach this value. (That may mean it sometimes increases as we increase $n$ - but it won't increase all the way to $1$.)

Answer (score 1):

After @Misha Lavrov's answer
$$r_{xy} = \frac{n\sum x_i y_i - \sum x_i\sum y_i}
{\sqrt{n\sum x_i^2-\left(\sum x_i\right)^2}~\sqrt{n\sum y_i^2-\left(\sum y_i\right)^2}}$$
$$r_{xy} =\frac{(n-1)\sqrt{15} }{\sqrt{(2 n-1) (8 n-11)}}$$

which is minimum for $n=4$; for this value $r_{xy}=\frac{3 \sqrt{5}}{7}=0.958315$.

If $n$ is large
$$r_{xy} =\frac{\sqrt{15}}{4} \left(1-\frac 1{16n}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac {a_k}{n^k}\right)$$ where all $a_k$'s are positive.